# undefiend is returned in the return value of Console log

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console

I have a program that changes the string depending on the number that comes in like this, but it returns "undefined" for the value... What is the cause of this?

Again, I don't know what the solution is and I need your help.

```
function size(num){
   if (num >= 1000) {
       console.log('a')
   } else if(num >= 500) {
       console.log('b')
   } else if(num >= 300) {
       console.log('c')
   } else {
       console.log('d')
   }
}
console.log(size(100));
```

Comment: your size function has no return statement - so it returns undefined - the console.log statements in that function are irrelevant to what you see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your size method doesnt return anything and therefore, the result is `undefined`.

I guess you wanted to return a value from the function and outside, `console.log` it.

Something like this:

```js
function size(num){
   if (num >= 1000) {
       return 'a';
   } else if(num >= 500) {
       return 'b';
   } else if(num >= 300) {
       return 'c';
   } else {
       return 'd';
   }
}
console.log(size(100));
```

A different approach would be to keep your original function and simply call it without `console.log`:

```js
function size(num){
   if (num >= 1000) {
       console.log('a')
   } else if(num >= 500) {
       console.log('b')
   } else if(num >= 300) {
       console.log('c')
   } else {
       console.log('d')
   }
}

size(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function size(num){
   if (num >= 1000) {
       console.log('a')
   } else if(num >= 500) {
       console.log('b')
   } else if(num >= 300) {
       console.log('c')
   } else {
       console.log('d')
   }
   
}
size(1000)
```

actually there is a problem in console.log() remove consloe from calling function otherwise remove it from if else